# C# exceptions global handler under interop scenario

Tags: c#, c++, exception, interop

First of all I am going to explain the scenario. We have a Visual C++ application with some C# projects and with some wrapper projects (managed C++) to get interoperability.

We need to be informed in Visual C++ side about exceptions in C# side. We know this can be achieved catching exceptions in our wrapper projects and re-throw them as C++ exceptions, we have tried this option and it works. We have also studied other options like catching asynchronous exceptions (c# exceptions) directly in C++ but we discard this last option because of the lack of information about the exception catched.

Wrapper projects are already written and are big enough to make us think about a solution that do not imply insert try/catch statements all over. We would like to set a global exception handler for C# exceptions that works as Visual C++ global handler does. We explore AppDomain.UnhandledException event but it does not fit for us because of [some interop issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx#id0070033) and, in any case, it breaks execution flow so we discard that option.

What we would like (that probably is not possible) is to set a C# global exception handler that allows us make the conversion and throw exceptions to Visual C++.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.